I can't make a core_user_create_users request - Moodle API
I tried to make like this:
http://url/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=token&wsfunction=core_user_create_users&moodlewsrestformat=json
body:
{
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "zezaoteste123",
      "password": "Segura5678!",
      "firstname": "zezao",
      "lastname": "teste",
      "email": "zezao.teste@dominio.com",
      "auth": "manual"
    }
  ]
}

But this errors persist:
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "Invalid parameter value detected (Missing required key in single structure: users)",
    "debuginfo": "Missing required key in single structure: users"
}

I need to create a user with Moodle API

hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659883/create-user-using-moodle-webservice?rq=2

saddly thats not my problem , i'm making the same request as told in this publication but still can't create a user

The moodlewsrestformat=json parameter refers only to the response generated by Moodle. It does not let it accept a json payload.
From Moodle's web service client documentation:

The moodlewsrestformat parameter affects the response format and can be either xml (default) or json.

In Postman, you must instead select x-www-form-urlencoded as the content type, and set the keys and values like this:



Key
Value




users[0][username]
zezaoteste123


users[0][firstname]
zezao


users[0][lastname]
teste


users[0][email]
zezao.teste@dominio.com



Alternatively, if you are able to install plugins, the moodle-webservice_restful plugin extends Moodle so it can accept json payloads.
